# Airflow Celery flower looks at the old config entry for mysql

Tags: airflow

I have tried to test airflow with celery. I changed `broker_url` and `celery_result_backend` to look at mysql.

So celery starts fine connecting to db but when I run `airflow flower` it seems that it reads a default config entry to connect to db.
this is what I am seeing in log:

```
[I 170420 13:51:38 mixins:231] Connected to sqla+mysql://airflow:airflow@localhost:3306/airflow
```

do I have to modify flower config somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

comment out the the **sql_alchemy_conn** config parameter in the **airflow.cfg** file